# How can I highlight a selected list item with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have several items in a list and want to highlight the one a user clicks on by applying some css style, maybe a background color etc.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img class="giftthumb" src='thumb1.jpg' alt="">
            <span class="gifttitle">Thumb1</span>
        </a>    
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img class="giftthumb" src='thumb2.jpg' alt="">
            <span class="gifttitle">Thumb3</span>
        </a>    
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img class="giftthumb" src='thumb3.jpg' alt="">
            <span class="gifttitle">Thumb3</span>
        </a>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQUery to retrieve selected item:

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    ???

})
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [class management methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) (namely `addClass()` and `removeClass()` in this case) to add a class on the selected item and remove the same class from all the other items (if you want only one selected at a time).

```
//save class name so it can be reused easily
//if I want to change it, I have to change it one place
var classHighlight = 'highlight'; 

//.click() will return the result of $('.thumbnail')
//I save it for future reference so I don't have to query the DOM again
var $thumbs = $('.thumbnail').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //run removeClass on every element
    //if the elements are not static, you might want to rerun $('.thumbnail')
    //instead of the saved $thumbs
    $thumbs.removeClass(classHighlight);
    //add the class to the currently clicked element (this)
    $(this).addClass(classHighlight);
});
```

Then in your CSS just add:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: cyan;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dtzjN/)

This is a better solution than changing CSS properties directly from jQuery/Javascript (with the `.css()` method for example), because separation of concerns will make your code more manageable and readable.

Comment: I've never seen syntax like this assigning a variable to the function...(e.g. $thumbs = )

Comment: @Paul I added some comments to explain that move. `$thumbs` will basically hold the result of `$('.thumbnail')`, because in jQuery most methods will return the jQuery collection to allow chaining. I did this because then inside the click handler, I don't have to query the DOM again for the `.thumbnail` elements, I already have them. If the elements are changing (I mean added/deleted), so not static, this method is not to be used, you should query the DOM again.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info. I'm always learning on this site :)

Comment: with the use of e.preventDefault(); it stops the page navigation for me?? any other solution @kapa

Comment: @htiru Then don't use it on the page navigation. Use it on the items you need highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ??? would be:

```
$('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

Then all you have to do is define your 'selected' css class.

Answer (score 1):

If you **don't** need the ***active*** to be **persistent** here's a CSS way:

```css
li:focus{
  background: red;
}
li:active{
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabindex="1">Item 1</li>
  <li tabindex="1">Item 2</li>
  <li tabindex="1">Item 3</li>
</ul>

Now click <b>here</b> and see why it's not persistent.
```

in some situations the above might be useful - to only highlight the currently "click-active" item…