# Giving an active li element a different background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to work on achieving some-thing like this as shown in the image taken from IP-Board's website. 
[ip image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzKFV.jpg)

My code is like the following:-

```
<ul class="navmenu">
 <li>//1st drop down box</li>
 <li>// 2nd drop down box</li>
```

Now I want the li items background to change to white when a user clicks on it. I know this can be done via Jquery but I am not very well versed with it. 
Hope any one of you can help me.

I tried this guide but did not work [How can I highlight a selected list item with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301356/how-can-i-highlight-a-selected-list-item-with-jquery)

Also please keep in mind that both the li elements contain jquery drop-downbox.

**UPDATE**
I want the Jquery so that if I click it once more the active class should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get active element by `:active` after selector like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/ELsC5/)

**CSS**

```
li:active{
    background:red;
}
```

## update:

if you want to background stay red you need  to use JQuery. first create a class that you want style the active item like this:

```
.active{
        background:red;
    }
```

then use this JQuery code:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

[**jsFiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/ELsC5/1/)

Comment: Well using this will not make it stay there permanent. The red background will just be seen for a split second before vanishing. So psudeo selector wont do the job.

Comment: @Balabky9: answer updated. style one `li` at the same time when you click on it.

Comment: Okay I am using MyBB. So will this Javascript affect all the li elements present?

Comment: Also should I add this script inside my HTML using <script>..</script> tags?

Comment: you can change selector as you wish like `ul.navmenu li` to work with special menu. and you can add `<script>` but you need to add [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) CDN, you can learn about it here: http://w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Comment: I have added the jquery from google CDN. Still its failing to function. Maybe I am adding it the wrong way.

Comment: this is a simple JQuery code, I think you need to learn about JQuery. I can not help you in comment posts!

Answer (score 1):

`$('ul li').on('click', function(){`
`$(this).addClass('highlight');`
`});`
and in css add class ".highlight"

`.highlight { background-color:red; }`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight{
    background-color: red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pisi2012/Bv9Da/)

Comment: I think he wants active one `li` in the same time, so this in not working, because you can active all items at the same time