# Highlight Selected Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two or more divs with the first being selected. When I click the other div, that div becomes selected. I'm doing this with a background color.

**CSS:**

```
.red {background: red}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="foo">...</div>
<div class="foo">...</div>
<div class="foo">...</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
 //$(this).toggleClass('red') Not ideal as the active div must always be red
 // If selected, remove all red classes then add class?
});
```

Since it's an event click, I'm not sure how to remove all other classes with red and add red class to the clicked div.

In short, "highlight" `div` when selected and if page is refreshed, the first `div` should have a background of red as that's the selected `div`.

Comment: It's better to use a class name that indicates why something looks the way it does, not how it looks. Here you could use `highlight`. `.highlight { background: blue; }` makes more sense than `.red { background: blue; }`.

Comment: @Arjan I'm rubbish with names but that's what I'm working on. In short, I only want to give the selected div a background color. If clicked twice, the background color does not change. On deeper research, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810821/highlight-div-onclick Many thanks for the supported questions and I could use them in other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method get sibling elements and remove `red` class from them.

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('red') // add class to clicked element
    .siblings() // get siblings
    .removeClass('red'); // remove class from sibling elements 
});
```

```js
$('.foo').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('red')
    .siblings().removeClass('red')
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">...</div>
<div class="foo">...</div>
<div class="foo">...</div>
```

Comment: I'd rather not to use `toggleClass` as it removes the class. But this works when used `addClass`. You see, If I click the same div twice, the class adds and removes with toggle.

Comment: @Sylar :  If you don't want to toggle then use `addClass`

Answer (score 1):

You want like this?

```js
$("#root").bind("click",function(e){
    $("#root").find(".foo").removeClass("red");
    $(e.target).addClass("red");
})
```

```css
.red {background: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div class="foo red">...</div>
  <div class="foo">...</div>
  <div class="foo">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the JS you want

```
$('.sample').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('addColor')
    .siblings().removeClass('addColor')
});
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tz6yrnxu/)