# Webview not working with HTML select element

Tags: java, android, html, webview

So my webview is not working with the select element. In other words when I click the select element on any page it does not show the menu.

html select element example:

```
<select>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>testing it</option>
    <option>bla bla bla</option>
</select>
```

java creating my webview:

```
        NestedWebView nwv = new NestedWebView(activity.getApplicationContext());
    nwv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    registerForContextMenu(nwv);
    nwv.setWebViewClient(new webViewClient());
    nwv.setWebChromeClient(new webChromeClient(nwv));
    nwv.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "drconsole");
    nwv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    nwv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    nwv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    nwv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    nwv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    nwv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    nwv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    nwv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    nwv.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    nwv.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    nwv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    nwv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    nwv.loadUrl(url);

    nwv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength){
            try{
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                String filename = new URL(url).getFile();

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) activity.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);

                Toast toast = new Toast(activity.getApplicationContext());
                View iview = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_toast, (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.toast_root));

                TextView text = (TextView) iview.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText("Downloading File");
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setView(iview);
                toast.show();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

my build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "deeproot.theanarch.org.deeproot"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

I also have almost everything possible for webviewclient and webchromeclient used. Please comment before you vote on my question.

Comment: Don't add the answer in the question, instead answer your own question.

Comment: I would love too. I cant yet though.

Comment: You can; click the add your own answer button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Fix this bug is that the webview MUST be initialized with the activity not the application context.

This line:

```
NestedWebView nwv = new NestedWebView(activity.getApplicationContext());
```

Must be:

```
NestedWebView nwv = new NestedWebView(activity);
```

Comment: Wow - you saved me a heart-attack.

Can you elaborate why is this so?

Comment: @Artyom Sure, the reasoning is the context its self, this issue can be found within recyclerViews as well. The reasoning is that some context is application, some is activity, I believe some can even be fragment. The webview requires the portions of the interface only available by the activity context and not found within the application context.

Answer (score -1):

You have to extend the WebViewClient, there is a detailed introduction how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350716/4159854

Comment: i have viewed this, however this is not a <select> element actually working.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Eloe.png